# Using an object pointer to access its member functions inside another class

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have an account class that has the data members accountNumber, accountBalance, and a pointer to a Person object, accountPerson. All of these are **protected** because Account is an abstract base class. My program reads info from a file and I am trying to call each objects own readData() methods.  For some reason, It is throwing an exception when I call accountPerson->readData(file);.

I am including just the readData functions from the class .cpp files.  Let me know if I need to include anything else.

Please take a look at my code and let me know if I'm missing something.

**Account.cpp**

```
void Account::readData(ifstream &ifile)
{
    string a;
    string b;

    if (ifile.fail() || ifile.bad())
        {
            throw readFileException("Could not read file");
        }
        else
        {
            getline(ifile, a);
            accountNumber = stoi(a);
            getline(ifile, b);
            accountBalance = stod(b);
            accountPerson->readData(ifile);
        }
}
```

**Person.cpp**

```
void Person::readData(ifstream &ifile)
{
    if (ifile.fail() || ifile.bad())
    {
        throw readFileException("Could not read file");
    }
    else
    {
        getline(ifile, name);
        getline(ifile, address);
    }
}
```

**Savings Account .cpp**

```
void Savings::readData(ifstream &ifile)
{
    string _a;
    if (ifile.fail() || ifile.bad())
    {
        throw readFileException("Could not read file");
    }
    else
    {
        ifile >> interest;
        ifile.ignore();
        Account::readData(ifile);
    }
}
```

**driver.cpp**

```
while (inFile.good())
{
    if (!inFile.eof()) //Loop to read in accounts and push them to vector
    {
        while (inFile >> type)
        {
            if (type == "Checking")
            {
                cout << type << endl;
                a[index] = new Checking();
            }
            else
            {
                cout << type << endl;
                a[index] = new Savings();
            }
            cout << index << endl;
            try
            {
                a[index]->readData(inFile);
            }
            catch (readFileException &e)
            {
                cout << "Error: " << e.getMessage() << endl;
                system("pause");
                exit(1);
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
} // end of while loop
```

The exception says:

> Exception thrown at 0x0016733B in Project3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00000014.

Any tips for a beginner would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: How is the pointer `accountPerson` given a value?

Comment: What kind of exception are you seeing?  Please include the code that calls `readData`.

Comment: "throwing an exception". 
what's that exception?

Comment: Lots of possibilities. We need to know what the exception is, and what sets up the pointers, as a memory access exception is most likely.

Comment: @aschepler   I have included the code where the readData function is called and the exception message above.

Comment: @TheDark the pointer is set to nullptr in the default constructor.

Comment: @JasonCarrick then never set after that? You just answered your own question.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode  Yes I did,  I updated it to call a new Person instead and now it works.  And now I feel like an idiot.